# WHENEVER OSERROR suppresses error messages

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, sqlplus

```
$ sqlplus <connstring> 2>&1 <<!
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE ROLLBACK;
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT FAILURE ROLLBACK;
SET ECHO ON;
@nonex.sql;
!
```

Produces

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Mon Apr 13 19:02:37 2015
<etc>

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
<bla-bla-bla>

SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database <etc>
```

So, if an error occurs, I cannot see the cause. I tried piping the output to a file to no avail so a message being overwritten by the following text is not an issue.

Commenting out the `WHENEVER OSERROR` line adds the expected message:

```
SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SP2-0310: unable to open file "nonex.sql"
SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g <etc>
```

But now, the error code is 0.

Is this a known problem? Are there any fixes/workarounds?

Comment: On my test machine (Oracle 11.2.0.3 on Oracle Linux Server release 6.4) your script prints the error message `SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> O/S Message: No such file or directory` and returns a 1 exit code.

Comment: Unfortunately, 11.2.0.3 is only available to those with an active support contract, and 11.2.0.2 still exhibits this bug. I'll now try with the latest XE client.

Comment: No luck, the latest XE client is 11.2.0.2, too. Bah!

Comment: Well, I confirmed this is fixed in Oracle 11.2.0.3 Linux. This answers my question so if you wish, convert this into an answer, and I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Problem is, the "WHENEVER OSERROR..." suppresses the SQL*Plus "SP-0310" error that gives the actual (non-existent) file path.